# NullPointerException at setCharacterEncoding(UploadRequestWrapper.java:83)

Tags: apache, jsf, tomcat7, myfaces, trinidad

I am trying to upload a file to server using trinidad fileupload ([tr:inputFile](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/fileUpload.html)) component but i get a

> NullPointerException at setCharacterEncoding(UploadRequestWrapper.java:83)

on pressing the commandButton.

My **XHTML file** contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" >
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <tr:form usesUpload="true">
            <tr:inputFile label="Upload:" valueChangeListener="#{myBackingBean.fileUploaded}"/>
            <tr:commandButton text="Begin"/>
        </tr:form>
    </ui:define>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

**the Backing Bean:**

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.UploadedFile;

public class MyBackingBean{
    ...
    public void fileUploaded(ValueChangeEvent event){
        UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile) event.getNewValue();
        if (file != null){
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                "Successfully uploaded file " + file.getFilename() +
                " (" + file.getLength() + " bytes)");
                context.addMessage(event.getComponent().getClientId(context), message);
                // Here's where we could call file.getInputStream()
        }
    }
}
```

**the WEB-INF/web.xml file:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class
</filter>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**I am using:**

1. Server: Tomcat 7.0.12
2. MyFaces 2.2.0
3. Trinidad 2.0.1
4. JSTL 1.2
5. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers / Version: Kepler Service Release 1

**Full output:**

```
Schwerwiegend: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/com.cargarantie.ws.claimshandler] threw exception [null] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.UploadRequestWrapper.setCharacterEncoding(UploadRequestWrapper.java:83)
at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.setRequestCharacterEncoding(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:581)
at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.setRequestCharacterEncoding(ExternalContextWrapper.java:416)
at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.setRequestCharacterEncoding(ExternalContextWrapper.java:416)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandler.initView(ViewHandler.java:339)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.initView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:191)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.initView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:49)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.doPrePhaseActions(RestoreViewExecutor.java:83)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:182)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:196)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the problem!**

I don't know if this approach is best way to solve the problem but it works.

1. Create your own SetCharacterEncodingFilter class and add it to your build path. [Source:](http://www.javaroad.jp/opensource/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java)

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.servlet.Filter;
   import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
   import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

   public class SetCharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {
       protected String encoding = null;
       protected FilterConfig filterConfig = null;
       protected boolean ignore = true;

       @Override
       public void destroy() {

           this.encoding = null;
           this.filterConfig = null;
       }

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

           // Conditionally select and set the character encoding to be used
           if (ignore || (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)) {
               String characterEncoding = selectEncoding(request);
               if (characterEncoding != null)
                   request.setCharacterEncoding(characterEncoding);
           }


           // Pass control on to the next filter
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
           Utilities.ConsoleMsg("Done.", this, "doFilter", 5);
       }

       @Override
       public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

           this.filterConfig = fConfig;
           this.encoding = fConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
           String value = fConfig.getInitParameter("ignore");
           if (value == null)
               this.ignore = true;
           else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
               this.ignore = true;
           else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
               this.ignore = true;
           else
               this.ignore = false;
       }

       protected String selectEncoding(ServletRequest request) {
           return (this.encoding);
        }


   }
   ```
2. Register the Filter in web.xml and set your init parameters.

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>UTFEncodingFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>path.to.your.package.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>encoding</param-name>
           <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>ignore</param-name>
           <param-value>false</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </filter>
   ```
3. Add `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute to all Connectors in `server.xml`. Example:

   ```
   <Connector port="8080"
              protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443"
              URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
   ```

**Sources:**

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-1744
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/core.1112/e22506/chapter_adf_trinid_messages.htm
- [Character encoding problems with tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400989/character-encoding-problems-with-tomcat)