# Tomcat encoding issue again

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, encoding

There are a lot of questions on StackOverFlow on this theme:

1. [Handling Character Encoding in URI on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233076/handling-character-encoding-in-uri-on-tomcat)
2. [Why the character is corrupted when use request.getParameter() in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365806/why-the-character-is-corrupted-when-use-request-getparameter-in-java)
3. [request.getParameter() does not display properly character encoding in java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086190/request-getparameter-does-not-display-properly-character-encoding-in-java-serv)
4. [Character encoding problems with tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400989/character-encoding-problems-with-tomcat)

There is also a link in Tomcat Wiki on this issue: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

So I didn't know what title to my question  I should write. Maybe you would help me with this one two.

The problem I came up with: when text with cyrillic characters comes from requests I'm getting the following request parameter value: `to ÐÐ¸Ð·Ð½ÐµÑ Ð¸ ÑÐ¸Ð½Ð°Ð½ÑÑ`.

So what I have for this moment:

1. All `jsp` files have UTF-8 encdoing like so:

> ```
> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
>   pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
> ```

2. In Eclipse->Preferances->General->Workspace->Text files encoding set to UTF-8
3. Database encoding is set to: `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;`
4. In `\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf` folder server.xml one of the connectors was modified to:

`<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
connectionTimeout="20000"   redirectPort="8443"
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`

5. Create Encoding filter with `doFilter` method:

   ```
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
           FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
       String requestEncoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
       if (requestEncoding == null) {
           request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
       }
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
   ```

When reading from `jsp` I've also tried to fetch parameters in different ways like:

```
 <a href="<c:url value="controller?command=viewFaculty"> 
<c:param name="name" value="${faculty.name}"/> </c:url>">${faculty.name}</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<c:url value="controller?command=viewFaculty"> <c:param name="name" value="${faculty.name}"/>
```

And I still get this ugly characters. Would you help me with some advice ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. The issue was that I edited not the original `server.xml`. I've noticed that `tomcat` has appeared in Eclipse project explorer as a bookmark to project called `Servers`. 
And some files lies in him, such as:

1. `catalina.policy`
2. `catalina.properties`
3. `context.xml`
4. `web.xml`
5. `tomcat-users.xml`
   and
6. `server.xml`

So it happened that tomcat already have preconfigured files and it just strange that edited by myself file `server.xml` in `\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf` folder differs from the one that lies in this project.

At the start of the question I've linked some answears to this problem and at the end of my post I want to share the one that I found recently, that seems to me as the best guide to this problem: [How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)