# How to set tomcat 8 container character encoding of request and response to UTF-8 intead of ISO-8859-1

Tags: tomcat8, servlet-3.0

We need to set  tomcat 8 container character encoding of request and response to UTF-8 intead of ISO-8859-1 , What is the setting for the same 
We tried setting as mentioned below , 
https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q1

But that requires creating filter etc. Is there any elegant way where we can just change some configuration set to make it applicable at container level

Answer (score 10):

Tomcat 8+ comes bundled with a filter to set the character encoding.

This is described in [Tomcat 8 Container Provided Filters](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Set_Character_Encoding_Filter).

This filter needs to be configured in your web.xml file plus a few other changes as below.

The following configuration works for

- Tomcat 8.0.30
- jdk1.8.0_66
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Microsoft JDBC driver (sqljdbc42.jar)

**Character Encoding Filter**

web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**JSP Page Encoding**

web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

**JSP Page Creation**

Only standard English characters should be used
ie no accented characters etc

**Database Character Types**

All character types for table columns should be Unicode types eg NCHAR, NVARCHAR & NTEXT.

**Database Connection String**

For a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with collation 'Latin1_General_CI_AS', it seems that the connection string does not need to be set to use UTF-8.

context.xml

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/gtraxDS" auth="Container"
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://ctceu-wgc-dv026:45666; databaseName=gtraxd2"
       username="myAppUsername"
       password="myAppPa55word"/>
```

**Strict Servlet compliance**

Do not set 'strict servlet compliance'.

From the [Tomcat 8 Migration Guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#URIEncoding)

```
The default value of URIEncoding attribute for HTTP and AJP connectors has been changed from
"ISO-8859-1" to be "UTF-8" (if "strict servlet compliance" mode is off, which is the default)
```

**File System Character Encoding**

Iterating & displaying contents of:

```
System.getProperties();
```

gives:

```
...
file.encoding       Cp1252
file.encoding.pkg   sun.io
...
```

It seems that the file encoding does not need to be changed

Answer (score 2):

Character encoding filter should be the first filter in the filter chain that accesses request parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with HTML pages returned by the controllers. there was no problem while running in IntelliJ IDEA 2018 but after building the war file and deploying it in tomcat there was encoding problem with HTML pages which were in project static folder. 
after a bit searching, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716878/tomcat-7-0-35-set-http-response-header-content-type-charset-for-static-html-file) life-saving answer and I added the below tag in the web.xml file of tomcat in C:\apache-tomcat\conf directory and everything just worked like a charm.

```
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html;charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
     </mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it was enough to setup tomcat's web.inf (/tomcat/8.0.33/conf/web.inf), specifically header.

instead of :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

i'm using now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```