# Change default charset of Tomcat 8 to UTF-8

Tags: java, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding, tomcat8

I want to change the default charset of Tomcat 8 server to UTF-8 to use all languages. Now it is changing Spanish or any other language to some other characters while posting a form values.

I have tried by changing web.xml as well as connection string in context.xml but not able to do so. Also, tried solution given [How to set tomcat 8 container character encoding of request and response to UTF-8 intead of ISO-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431915/how-to-set-tomcat-8-container-character-encoding-of-request-and-response-to-utf).

Please let me know if my question is not clear or you need to anything else. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set tomcat 8 container character encoding of request and response to UTF-8 intead of ISO-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431915/how-to-set-tomcat-8-container-character-encoding-of-request-and-response-to-utf)

Comment: @TuanBA I have already tried, but it didn't work. May be I am missing something that why I have posted the question.