ḗ character from frontend in tomcat being parsed as?
my problem is that when I send the word including the 'ḗ' character using the REST interface, it is being transformed to '?' in tomcat. Please let me know if you need more information to solve this problem.
Tomcat version is 9.0.63.

I'll follow this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400989/character-encoding-problems-with-tomcat before I did changes to server.xml and web.xml but didn't close all running instances of Tomcat, but that one that I wanted to test.

Guess Your tomcat 9 run on Windows ?

Yes, more information is required: Please check [ask]. Also, you might want to read on the topic of "encoding" in the context of Tomcat, REST and the client you send the request from.
